# Flutter -- Dynamic Textformfield Inputs

Tags: flutter

How to deal with dynamic textformfield input. Basically I want to get input from differnt texfield without texteditingConroller.

Can anyone guide me with that?

Comment: does onChange work for your problem?

Comment: I want to add dynamic textfield. But If i use onChange it will change multiple textfield at same time.